# How can one use the ARMv6 Optimized OpenMAX DL Libraries with the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, assembly, arm

There are assembly language libraries for the ARM for doing signal processing and other good stuff called "OpenMAX DL for ARM11 processor family".

When you download the library from the ARM site, it contains .s assembly files. How can these be compiled with Xcode and called from Objective-C for the iPhone? There are examples of inline assembly but I can't find info on using .s assembly files.

Comment: did you have any success building openmax for iphone?

Comment: I didn't get the assembly to compile. But the C files that I tired were fine.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can compile assembly file using X-code. Just add the assembly files *.s to the projects and build the project. The assembly file is gets assembled and linked.

Don't forget to include needed *.h files in your code and then call as normal function.

You can read more details here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/16804-calling-assembly-functions-c.html

---

**Edit:** there are much MACROses in ARMv6-optimized OpenMAX libraries, and maybe some of them are RealView-specific. So they can compile in X-code or can not compile. Maybe this is your problem.